# Right way for conditional transition depending on where view is rendered in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

Hi I have a view call AutocompleteView its job is to put google places autocomplete on landing page.There is no map rendered on this page just a textbox.
what I am try to achieve is user should just use autocomplete textbox on landing page. On entering some place of choice. I will transition the user to a specific route where the same AutocompleteView will be rendered with map so tha user can change his choice of place.

When user chang the location on the page where map is rendered no transition is needed here

the approch I am trying is I check the parent view where

```
{{view AutocompleteView}}
```

has been rendered using `this.get('ParentView")` and based on the parent view

say if ParentView is Application(landing page) I will transition or else no transition will occur.

I have no good experienve of javascript mvc my doubt

**Is it right to rely on ParentView for just transtions or is there a better way??**

```
App.AutocompleteAddressView = Ember.View.extend({
tagName: 'input',
didInsertElement: function() {
    var options = {
        componentRestrictions: {country: "xx"}
    };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.$()[0], options);
    console.log(this.get('parentView'));
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to handle the action of "entering text in the search box" differently based on which route is currently active -- the landing page or the results page.

The Ember way to do this is to trigger an action from your view using `this.get('controller').send(#{actionName})`. That action will bubble up from the view's controller to the current route. Then you can handle that action differently depending on which route is active, e.g.:

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  ...
  actions: {
    search: function() {
      # transition to results page
    }
  }
});

App.ResultsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  ...
  actions: {
    search: function() {
      # update visible results
    }
  }
});
```

To make this easier, you might want to use a subclass of [`Ember.TextField`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html) for your `AutocompleteAddressView`. Then you can define an `action` property on your view that will automatically get triggered when the user types enter/return.